# Bash script is indented inconsistently

Tags: indentation

Open the code below with `emacs -q`, do `set-variable sh-basic-offset 2`, then `indent-region`. All lines are indented with 2, while the `echo` line is indented with 4. Is this a bug in Emacs, or how do I configure it to indent consistently with 2? (When setting to 8, `echo` is still indented with 4.)

Using latest release GNU Emacs 25.3.1 on macOS installed with Homebrew.

```
#!/bin/bash

hello() {
  while true; do
    if [ true ]; then
    ····echo true
    fi
  done
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't see this problem in my local Emacs, so maybe it's a bug that was fixed since the release you're using?

Comment: @Stefan: Added version information. Did you try this with `emacs -q` to make sure none of your `.emacs` settings interfere with testing? If the bug happens with `-q` and doesn't without, I'd be interested in hearing which `.emacs`setting of your makes things work.

Comment: I was able to reproduce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [bug](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21751), fixed in version 26.1. As a workaround you can set both the variables `sh-indentation` and `sh-basic-offset` to 2.